# simple JavaScript to get type="radio" values to summary

Tags: javascript

Appreciate in advance the help :)
Have tried a few things but getting stuck and no output.

Have a form.html that gathers data and using jquery gets the values to the summary.html. Having trouble with getting the values of the radio button 'gender'.

form.html

```
    <label for="firstname">First Name:</label><input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" autofocus placeholder="John" required="required" maxlength="15" />
    <br>
    <label for="surname">Surname:</label><input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" placeholder="Smith" required="required" maxlength="30" />
    <br>
    <br>

    Gender:
    <input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /><label for="male">Male</label>
    <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /><label for="female">Female</label>
    <input id="prefernotsay" type="radio" name="gender" value="prefernotsay" checked /><label for="prefernotsay">Prefer Not to Say</label>
    <br>   

    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
    <br>    
</form>
```

summary.html

```
<body>
<table>
    <tr>         
        <td id="firstname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="surname" /></td>
    </tr>      
    <tr>
        <td id="gender" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js

```
window.onload = function () {
"use strict";

var url = new URL(window.location.href);

var firstname = url.searchParams.get("firstname"); document.getElementById("firstname").innerText = firstname;

var surname = url.searchParams.get("surname"); document.getElementById("surname").innerText = surname;    

var radios = document.getElementsByName('gender');

for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        alert(radios[i].value);
        break;
    }
}
```

};

Comment: I see a couple things, 1. you are calling all this code on window load.  I assume you would want to do it on form submit or button click. 2. I don't see any use of jQuery here, this is all js dom selectors.

Comment: what's the issue or error you are getting?

Comment: Also, I assume the second html is the page you are posting to. It does not contain any radio buttons, you need to get the value like you are getting the other values  document.getElementById("gender").innetText = url.searchParams.get("gender")

Comment: Yeh sorry. simple dom selectors trying to learn some functionalities slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selected value in a radio button group, you want to select the `:checked` element in the group and get it's `.val()`.  Here's a simple version you can run and observe:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var gender = $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();
    
    alert('Gender = ' + gender);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div>
    Gender
    <input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /><label for="male">Male</label>
    <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /><label for="female">Female</label>
    <input id="prefernotsay" type="radio" name="gender" value="prefernotsay" checked /><label for="prefernotsay">Prefer Not to Say</label>
  </div>
  
  <div><input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Just re-read your question: you're trying to display the selected value on the page that your form is submitting to, not on the page the form is being displayed on?  In that case, using `url.searchParams.get("gender")` and using that value seems like the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank You! Sorry for confusing with my question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are sending the params from your form to your second page, you should be getting the value for gender from the searchParams just like the other values

```
window.onload = function () {
    var url = new URL(window.location.href);

    document.getElementById("firstname").innerText = url.searchParams.get("firstname");

    document.getElementById("surname").innerText = url.searchParams.get("surname");    

    document.getElementById("gender").innerText = url.searchParams.get("gender");
}
```

Comment: OP's question specifically asks for jQuery solution.

Comment: If you look at his example, he is not getting the values with JQuery at all.

Comment: Yeah, just re-read the body of the question - the question's title is misleading.  I just submitted an edit to the question `s/jquery/JavaScript/`.  :-)

Comment: sorry for confusing with my question